# Poor text editing performance from the radeon open source driver; should I install proprietary driver or try to fix this?

Tags: drivers, video, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I followed the steps at the link below to remove the proprietary driver and install the Radeon open source driver.

RadeonDriver - Community Ubuntu Documentation
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

However, now I notice that when I'm editing text (such as in this website) if I delete lines a few adjacent lines may completely disappear until I scroll or edit again. This bothers me enough that I need to make a change. Should I go back to the proprietary driver?

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04 with a Radeon HD 6750 card and 3 monitors (one at 2560x1600 resolution and the other 2 at 1920 x 1200). Maybe that is too much for the open source driver?

Recommendations?

Comment: what web browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox. Firefox was fine before I changed video drivers from fglrx to radeon open source.

Comment: I'd switch back then.

Comment: whether you switch back to fglrx or not, i'd still recommend disabling smooth-scrolling and hw acceleration - in my experience, they're nothing but trouble.

Comment: That's interesting. I have both of those enabled (and those have been my settings for a long time). I will try disabling them before I switch drivers. Thanks

Comment: I always thought this was a bug in firefox... when it happens I just hit ctrl-A to highlight the whole box and that forces it to repaint.

Comment: @psusi - interesting. I have never encountered it before. I have been using Linux around 6-7 years.

Comment: I'm not happy about it, but I decided to go back to the proprietary fglrx driver. My system was generally a lot slower with the open source driver and I like Firefox to work the way it worked with the fglrx driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched back to the proprietary fglrx driver. I notice several things:

1. The Firefox text editing bug is gone.
2. In general usage application windows open a lot faster.
3. KDE 4.11.1 has a minor bug with the fglrx driver that will be fixed in the next point release: window side borders are not drawn at first (but appear after a focus change).

I could not tolerate the Firefox text editing bug or the general slowness with the open source radeon driver, so I switched back to the fglrx driver even though I would prefer the open source driver in ideal circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firefox (aka Iceweasel), try disabling autoscrolling, smooth scrolling and hardware acceleration.

You can do that in:  Edit Menu -> Preferences -> Advanced Tab -> General

Comment: The "Check my spelling as I type" option is also a performance hit.  I have all four options under "Browsing" disabled.